# What happens when we Switch User in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, user-switching

I have an old Windows 7 laptop. When I lock it (for example, using *WinKey + L*), it takes about half a second to show the lock screen. But then, when I click the *Switch User* button, it can take a full minute. As slow as my laptop is, the difference between these two operations is pretty noticeable.

So, what goes on in Windows when I click *Switch User* that's so much slower to complete than locking?

Comment: Swapping all your programs out to disk and loading the other user's programs?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not talking about actually logging in as another user, but just falling back to the users selection screen. Still, swapping all my programs to disk sounds a pretty reasonable cause for the slowdown. Is there any documentation or other material that confirms this?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis try this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279782 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9d5ccd4e-41c5-40b1-91dd-fb765a1018a6/how-does-switch-user-works-internally-in-windows?forum=w7itprogenera